# Приоритет сетевых интерфейсов в Windows

Tags: windows, сеть, tcp-ip, приоритет

Всем привет!

Имеется ПК на Windows с двумя сетевыми адаптерами: адаптер1 (1 ГБит/с) и адаптер2 (100 МБит/с). Адаптер2 подключен к интернету. Адаптер1 подключен к кастомному устройству (диагностический прибор), который оцифровывает сигналы и небольшмими порциями передает по TCP/IP на ПК, в зависимости от настроек забивая гигабитный канал на 30-90%.

Проблема: если не использовать интернет через адаптер2, то график загрузки адаптера1 стабильно держит определенное значение без скачков, данные с устройства приходят с +- стабильным интервалом (25-30 мс). Если начать пользоваться интернетом через адаптер2 (например загрузка интернет страниц) в графике загрузки адаптера1 появляются провалы, данные начинают приходить с ощутимым лагом (300 - 2000 мс).
Пробовал выставить приоритет сетевых подключений вот таким образом: Сетевые подключения -> Свойства -> IP версии 4 -> Свойства -> Дополнительно -> Метрика интерфейса, но это не дало результатов.

Собственно вопрос, как задать приоритет сетевых адаптетов, что бы трафику с адаптера1 ни чего не мешало?
Приветсвуются любые советы, идеи, уточняющие вопросы или направления в которые нужно копать
Не использовать интерент или вообще отключать все остальные адаптеры на время работы с устройством  прошу не предлагать :)

Comment: На сколько я помню, то windows вроде как обрабатывает IP последовательно, т.е. все идёт примерно через одну "трубу"

Comment: Расскажите об адаптерах: оба встроенные на MB, оба внешних и т.п.?

Comment: Адаптер1 - встроенный Realtec PCI GbE Family Controller, адаптер2 - Realtec USB FE Family Controller (USB-сетевуха DEXP). В качестве адаптера2 пробовали использовать в том числе сетевую карту подключаемую к PCI и Wi-Fi модуль подключаемые к USB, ситуация не менялась, адаптер1 лагал при использовании адаптера2